# Javascript function not getting called in another domain

Tags: javascript, html

Not sure why the below function "test" is not getting called here.I am trying to debug this from previous 3 hours.pls suggest or advise.Below is my html code :

The below code is working fine in one domain..but when I Xfer the files to another domain..then the test function is not getting called .

```
<html>
<head><title>The Website Is Under Construction</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function defaultcity()
{        
    $("#list").load("pune.php");
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });         
}
function display_details(shopname,img,shopcode)  
{  

$( "#reviews" ).empty();
document.getElementById("reviews").style.display='none';





document.getElementById("menu").style.display='block';       



var a = document.getElementById("1");
a.onclick = function(){
document.getElementById("reviews").style.display='none';
document.getElementById("photo_gallery").style.display='none';
document.getElementById("menu_card").style.display='none';
return false;
};


var c = document.getElementById("3");
c.onclick = function(){
alert("This is the onclick of Reviews button..after that I am going to call a   javascript function test() which is successfully getting called here but not in   HOSTING24..pls click on OK and see");
test();
document.getElementById("photo_gallery").style.display='none';
document.getElementById("menu_card").style.display='none';
document.getElementById("reviews").style.display='block';
return false;
}; 





 $("#reviews").load("loadn.php?   shopcode="+encodeURIComponent(shopcode)+"&shopname="+encodeURIComponent(shopname)+"&img="+e ncodeURIComponent(img));

 return false;
 }




</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor=#3B0B0B topmargin="5" bottommargin="0" leftmargin="80" rightmargin="80" onLoad="defaultcity()" >
<script>

function test(){

alert("This function is not getting called on HOSTING24");  
}

</script>
<div  id="header" valign=top   style="background-color:#0B0B61" align="right"> 
<font color=white>City

<select  name="city" id="city" onchange="selectarea()">
<option value="">Select...</option>

<?php
include './connection.php';
$query1 = "select * from cities";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
echo '<option value="' . $row1['name'] . '">';
echo $row1['name'];
echo '</option>';

 }
 echo '</select>';
 ?>
 Area
 <div id="areas" name="areas" style="display: inline-block;" >
<select>
<option>select
</option>
</select>

 </div>



 </font>
 <font color=white>My Settings | Password Management | Help | Logout</font></div>
<div align="center">


</div>





</div>


 <button onclick="display_details('abd','abc 9.jpg','10')" type="button" >Click me          </button>
 <br>






<br>
<br>








<table class="ex1" border="1" width="100%" align=center height="330px" class="fixed">
<col width="77px" />
<col width="23px" />


<tr valign=top>
<td width="77%" id="table1">


<table border="1" width="100%" id="table_title">
<tr>
<td>


</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="menu" align="center" align="middle">
<ul>
<li><a id="1" href="#" >Home</a></li>

<li><a id="3" href="#" >Reviews</a></li>

</ul>
 </div>

<div id="reviews" ></div>



</td>

 <td width="23%">

<div><img id="elem1" width="250px" height="250px"></div>
<div id="desc" style="color:white" ></div>



</tr>
</table>










<div id="footer" align="center" style="background-color:#0B0B61">
 Copyright © 2014 XYZ Consultancy Services | About XYZ |
Terms of Use | Sitemap | Feedback Form | Browser and Display Compatibility
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way: [don't use jQuery latest](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/)

Comment: already tried..but not working

Comment: It sure would make it easier to decipher your code if you indented it properly in your question.

Comment: can you format the code properly and create a pen or fiddle with the problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it makes our eyes bleed. Format it like we were humans. There should also be a fiddle that reproduces the problem - with code identical to what you have posted in the question itself. It only takes you to do it once. So do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line of code:

```
 $("#reviews").load("loadn.php?   shopcode="+encodeURIComponent(shopcode)+"&shopname="+encodeURIComponent(shopname)+"&img="+e ncodeURIComponent(img));
```

There is a space in:

```
e ncodeURIComponent(img)
```

which makes an error.  I also don't know why you want the spaces in your URL either.

---

Beyond that, I'd suspect that something in the PHP might be different from one server to the next.  You could better compare that if you looked at the generated HTML page (what the browser sees in View/Source) from both servers and see what differences there are in the two pages.

Also, look in the debug console to see what errors (if any) are being reported?

Comment: aah igonore that ...the space actually appeared while copy pasting ..

Comment: @user3848480 - and what about your PHP environment being different?  Did you compare the generated HTML from both sites to see that it was identical?  Did you look for console errors in the browser?  Also, if you don't intend for those spaces to be there, then please edit your question to fix them so others don't wonder about them too.

Comment: I have removed all the php code from the page and now the function is successfully getting called...but now the concern is why there is PHP issue here as I require the php part..Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: @user3848480 - look at the generated browser pages to see where the PHP went wrong/different.  Or debug your PHP server code when it generates the page to see what is different.  I don't know PHP, but it looks to me like you're connecting to a local database and running a query.  So, either you don't have the right data in the copy of the local database or don't have some necessary PHP scripts installed on the other copy.